How to style syntax only on delimiter close?
[Menu bar > Language > User Defined Language (v2.1.0.12)]
In the custom language I defined, I'm changing the style of the text based on if something is enclosed between asterisks (*).
It works but the style I set applies to the text before I close it. I don't want that.
Picture to show what I mean

What I want is to stylize only if there is an asterisk at the end.
How do I define this style?
